# Transparency/dim/beamercovered does not work properly on Beamer

Tags: beamer, overlays, transparency

I am writnig Aribic on beamer using minipage and begin arabic, the problem is that transparency  applies on bullets and except the text, here is the MWE:

```
    % !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[secheader]{Madrid}
%
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
%
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setotherlanguage[calendar=gregorian,numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1]{Times New Roman}%
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic,Scale=1]{Times New Roman}%
%
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Animation}
%\begin{minipage}{0.95\textwidth}
\begin{Arabic}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> Item one
\begin{enumerate}
\item<3-> Item three
\item<4-> Item four
\end{enumerate}
\item<2-> Item two
\end{itemize}
\end{Arabic}
%\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Items frequency disorder]

Comment: Good question!!

Comment: .... but very easy to fix :)